# Display console.log output in IntelliJ without debugging

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm running a JavaScript program and I'm wondering if there is a way to see the `console.log` without switching to the browser. I can see the `console.log` output in the debug console when I debug but I'm trying to see such an output without getting into debug.

Googled and couldn't find any good answer.

Comment: no way to do this. You can clear all breakpoints and then debug your app to see logging in debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Accomplishing this task is not a straightforward process. You will need to create JavaScript functions that can substitute the console functions of the browser and transmit them to the backend using WebSockets or similar technology.

Comment: Is there no in built settings or plugins in Intellij that I can use?